# Mongoose - search a complex nested document and update some fields of a sub-document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update some fields of mongoose sub-document according to provided keys from postman req.body.

I have tried some couple of solutions but to no successful end. I will like to loop through the req.body and update the necessary fields. like i have tried under the  "//update function"

Here is my schema.

```
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    profile: {
        full_name: {
            first_name: String,
            last_name: String
        },
        phone: Number,
        email: String,
        gender: String,
        address: {
            city: String,
            street: String,
        },
        occupation: String,
        biography: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at'
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Assistant', assistantSchema);
```

Here is my update route where I will like to update the values

```
router.patch('/:assistantId', Check_Auth, async (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.assistantId;

//update function
    const updateParams = req.body;
    const set = {};
    for (const field of updateParams) {
        set['assistant.$.' + field.key] = field.value
    }

//update
    try {
        await Assistant.updateOne({
            _id: id
        }, {
            $set: set
        }).exec().then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json(result)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(403).json({
                errmsg: "Ooh something happen, Not able to update profile try again"
            })
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            errmsg: err
        })
    }
});
```

Here is my are the values from postman

````
[
    {"key": "phone", "value": "651788661"},
    {"key": "email", "value": "dasimathias@gmail.com"},
    {"key": "city", "value": "douala"},
    {"key": "street", "value": "bonaberi"},
    {"key": "biography", "value": "just share a little code"}
]
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the data you're sending as a post request, the object you're passing to `$set` looks like this :

```
{ 'assistant.$.phone': '651788661',
  'assistant.$.email': 'dasimathias@gmail.com',
  'assistant.$.city': 'douala',
  'assistant.$.street': 'bonaberi',
  'assistant.$.biography': 'just share a little code' }
```

This is inconsistent with your schema, if you are trying to update the `profile` attribute you would do this :

```
for (const field of updateParams) {
  if(field.key == "city") set[`profile.address.${field.key}`] = field.value
  else set[`profile.${field.key}`] = field.value
}
```

Which gives an object `set` like this:

```
{ 'profile.phone': '651788661',
  'profile.email': 'dasimathias@gmail.com',
  'profile.address.city': 'douala',
  'profile.street': 'bonaberi',
  'profile.biography': 'just share a little code' 
}
```

Note that `city` is nested inside `address` so you need to access it, you would have to do the same (condition) for `full_name`.
If you're updating an array of subdocuments:

```
set[`assistant.$.profile.address.${field.key}`]
set[`assistant.$.profile.${field.key}`]
```